# How to custom hide bottom aligned view using custom CoordinatorLayout Behavior

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I'd like to hide a `View` aligned to the bottom of my `Fragment` used within a `ViewPager` when the `RecyclerView` in the same fragment animates.

I'm able to apply the `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior` `Behavior` to the view and have the `View` start off as hidden and then animate in when scrolling down.  When scrolling back up, the view hides.  (This behavior matches what the `TabLayout` toolbar does with scroll|enterAlways `scrollFlags` set.)

What I'd like is the opposite of this. The `View` starts off as visible, and scrolls downwards to hide itself when scrolling down, then shows itself again when scrolling up.

Is this possible?

My activity XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
        <!-- This is where I set the behavior for the fragment used in the viewpager-->

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="2dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My Fragment XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text_view"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Bottom Bar Test"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks
Zach

UPDATE 1:
I get close to the desired behavior by using the following custom `Behavior` class.  When scrolling, the bottom bar does scroll off in the right direction! However, there is a white space that appears at the top of the view as well, sized to be the height of the bottom view that is currently hidden.  I do not think the animations are supposed to be used in this manner, maybe?

```
public class BottomBarScrollOffBehavior extends AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior
{
    private int appBarHeight;

    public BottomBarScrollOffBehavior()
    {
    }

    public BottomBarScrollOffBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency)
    {
        appBarHeight = dependency.getMeasuredHeight();
        return super.onDependentViewChanged(parent, child, dependency);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setTopAndBottomOffset(int offset)
    {
        return super.setTopAndBottomOffset(appBarHeight - offset);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your xml file?

Comment: Done, edited the original post.

Comment: where do you specify the behaviour of you view?

Comment: Ah, good catch.  I will update my layout again.  I had removed the behavior here to show the default behavior.

Comment: Did you solve this? If not, check out https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/ for some ideas that might help.

Comment: I've since moved on from this in general - decided on a UX that did not use the coordinator layout behavior unfortunately.  I'll circle back and check that out when I have some downtime.  Thank you very much!